# How can I get the name of the DeploymentItem?

Tags: c#, mstest, deploymentitem

I would like to get rid of some duplication in this code. Following the DRY principle.
As you can see, the name of the file/deploymentItem is repeated.

```
[TestMethod]
[DeploymentItem("TestData/TestExcel.xlsx")]      <-- 
public void GivenAnExcel_ConverToPDF()
{
    const string filename = "TestData/TestExcel.xlsx";     <-- 
    var result = pdfConverter.ConvertExcelDocument(filename);
    AssertIsPdf(result);
}
```

- Is there a way to access the DeploymentItem programmatically without using the filename?
  Or
- Can I get filename programmatically somehow?

*No, I cannot use another test framework than mstest ;-)*

Comment: Thank you for this question @Peter! I had the same wish (getting rid of these duplications) but I was sure there is not any way :-)
A constant in an attribute... *Thanks* @Schaliasos!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do this:

```
[TestClass]
public class Test
{
    const string filename = "TestData/TestExcel.xlsx";

    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(filename)] 
    public void GivenAnExcel_ConverToPDF()
    {
        var result = pdfConverter.ConvertExcelDocument(filename);
        AssertIsPdf(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lol! Bizarre that I didn't realize this... A const in an attribute... THANKS!!